# Change file name in Azure Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I've write the data in the pyspark dataframe using the dataframe writer APIs.
How can I change the name of the csv file generated?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to get a single CSV file out of a Spark Dataframe, using the spark.write.csv() method. This will create a distributed file by default.
I would recommend the following instead if you want a single file with a specific name.

`df.toPandas().to_csv('/dbfs/path_of_your_file/filename.csv')`

using Pandas to_csv arguments that fit your need.

Comment: how to parametrize the filename part?

Comment: You could use an fstring. Declare a variable ```filename = "name_of_my_file ``` and then
```df.toPandas().to_csv(f'/dbfs/path_of_your_file/{filename}.csv') ```